# Adding Images into API

Tags: post-thumbnails, api, rest-api

I'm trying to add featured images to my API but it's a different type of post.

http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/directory

I have been using WP REST API Controller but it doesn't show image option.

I also try to use "Better REST API Featured Images" but no luck.

It's starting to annoy me.

Comment: can you show what you've tried?

Comment: I added the directory?_embed  using the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-rest-api-featured-images/ here's the api I'm trying to add it too http://bakersfielddba.com/wp-json/wp/v2/directory?_embed

Comment: You can try to add a image as a media element (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/) and after you associate the media ID to your custom posts.

Comment: I did that but the issue with it doesn't always match with the media ID

Comment: it's a different type of post I also been trying to use other ideas but nothing working out , I event try this script out https://www.wpsaga.info/wp-rest-api-get-featured-image-with-custom-endpoint/

Answer (score 0):

from the support forum of that plugin:

Your cpt may not be registered correctly.  Try adding this to your functions.php (change "event" to your post type slug):

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', function( $args, $post_type ) {

if( 'event' === $post_type ) {
    $args['show_in_rest'] = true;
}

return $args;

}, 10, 2 );
```

or make sure that you have show in rest active for your cpt when you actually registered it.